# Recursively lowercase, replace space and remove invalid characters on linux FS

Tags: linux, filesystems

I want to recursively run the following commands on a directory as part of a cron.

The first line changes everything to lowercase, the second replaces spaces with _ and the third removes all invalid chars.

Any advice would be appreciated.

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" "`echo $f | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"`"; done
for i in *; do mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed -e 's, ,_,g'`"; done
for f in *;do mv "$f" "${f//[^0-9A-Za-z_.]}";done
```

Comment: One way is use the find utility to recursively find all the files and exec a shell script to modify each file name as necessary.

Comment: I probably wouldn't run something like this via cron. What is producing the files? Can this be fixed upstream?